Return RedirectToAction not returning the target page?
I have written a code which first performs an action to insert new Object into the Table and post that I have a code from Twillio which sends a msg to WhatsApp. The complete code is working fine, only the last call where I want to return url to another page stays like LOADING and fails to return the target page.
[HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult ClientDeal(Models.VM.Client model, FormCollection formCollection, int CoOrdName)
{

using (Db db = new Db())
{
   //This works good
}

var accountSid = "AC811e03512598d0fb1588a948d8c0af95";
var authToken = "4aba7186a0637735c0a42718485f1c71";
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var messageOptions = new CreateMessageOptions(
new PhoneNumber($"whatsapp:{agentPhone}"));
messageOptions.From = new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+14155238886");
messageOptions.Body = msg;
var message = MessageResource.Create(messageOptions);
TempData["SM"] = "New Lead successfuly assigned!";

return RedirectToAction("AgentOpenDeal","Deal");

}

Any suggestions?
Thank you

If RedirectToAction is not working as expected, consider moving the POST action to the controller that you want to return to. By doing this, you ensure that the action and the view are handled within the same controller, which can help resolve issues with redirection.
public class AgentOpenDeal : Controller
{
    private readonly IClientService _clientService;

    public AgentOpenDeal(IClientService clientService)
    {
        _clientService = clientService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ClientDeal(Models.VM.Client model, FormCollection formCollection, int CoOrdName)
    {
        await _clientService.InsertClientAsync(model, formCollection);
        await _clientService.SendMessageAsync(agentPhone, msg);

        TempData["SM"] = "New Lead successfully assigned!";

        // Return the view directly
        return View("Deal");
    }
}


To improve code organization and reusability, consider moving the logic to a service. This way, you can reuse the code in different parts of the application and keep the controller cleaner.

Thank you for you suggestions. really helpful

The issue was with the .NET Framework, as it was not in sync with Twilio version. I had to re-install the Twilio NuGet package, and then the issue was resolved.

Can you [edit] your answer to clarify what version of the NuGet package you had to upgrade from and to?

Done @JeremyCaney

It looks like you edited your question to include the answer. Please don’t do that. You had done it correctly originally when you posted an answer. You just need to [edit] your answer to include the specific versions. Remember, people may (and likely will!) be reading this thread for years to come, so being clear what version had the issue, and what version solved the issue will help people avoid a lot of frustration in the future.
